# Этимология слова "не-я"

Tags: этимология, орфография

Как появилось слово *не-я*? Калька ли это?

Почему оно пишется через дефис?

Answer (score 1):

**Дефисное написание можно объяснить и с точки зрения русского языка.**

"Не-я" не является отрицанием, это утвердительное название:  таким образом в философии противопоставлены субъект (я) и объект (не-я).

Соответственно, раздельное написание исключается,  а из двух других выбираем дефис (слово со слитным написанием  "нея" просто не будет узнано).

Comment: Это будет не совсем корректным, так как *не-я* — **калька**, причем *словообразовательная*. Тем не менее ваше объяснение можно применить и к немецкому языку.

Comment: Если бы у нас был выбор, тогда можно было  бы говорить о словообразовательных кальках. Но у нас выбора нет, и это главный аргумент.

Comment: Простите, а что за выбор?

Comment: Выбор формы письма: слитное и раздельное написание невозможны.

Comment: Так и что? Мы калькируем какой-нибудь там skyscraper и получаем небоскреб. Есть ли выбор?

Comment: Или я просто недопонимаю? Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем суть.

Comment: Может быть, я Вас не понимаю. Nicht-Ich - это не-я. Это выражение мы не можем записать по-русски иначе, чем через дефис. Это и означает, что нет выбора.

Comment: я про то, что это **калька**, то есть да, выбора нет, но по причине калькирования (имхо). Понял вашу позицию. А вы не знаете случаев, где, допустим, в языке-источнике есть дефис, а в кальке уже нет?

Comment: Не знаю, как раз хотела это у Вас спросить.

Comment: попробую позже задать вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вообще-то дефисное написание единственно возможное. 
По общим правилам понятие с отрицанием пишется слитно.
Но к местоимениям такое просто неприменимо в силу во-первых, что отрицания с местоимением пишутся слитно совсем в других случаях, а во-вторых, что тут совершенно не воспринимается.

В отношении немецкого написания - не думаю, что, во-первых, оно критично, а во-вторых, что именно оно стало источником. Там - тот же случай. слитное написание совершенно не воспринималось бы зрительно.

По поводу источника. 
Да, есть такое понятие философии, но ведь есть и совершенно бытовое (пусть и ироническое) использование?

-- Кто это сделал?
 -- Это не я!
 -- Ну вот пусть не-я все и исправит.

Короче, я вообще не думаю, что это калька.
Калька (лингвистическая) обычно является переводом слова "по частям", в результате образуется новое понятие. Сравните: насекомое: фр. «insecte» (от лат. insectum) - сечь, рассекать. что тут рассечено, не сразу и догадаешься. Это типичная калька.

А тут и в языке-источнике и в языке-цели целиком выводится из составляющих. Это не калька, это просто перевод.

Comment: Но меняет значение не всегда: skyscraper тот же. А с *насекомым* точно образуется новое понятие? В греческом ἔντομον тоже насекомое (в лат. тоже и т. д.)

Comment: ***Новое понятие - в языке источнике***, если вдруг вы не поняли. Из составляющих прямо не вытекающее. skyscrape - именно что новое понятие. Не вытекающее из исходных sky + to scape. Сравните с укр. "хмаро+чос" (=тучечесалка)  - та же модель, совершенно другое наполнение (хотя и через близкие понятия). Ну и с насекомым, естественно, то же самое.  .

Comment: Ну, собственно, *не-я* философское совсем не то же, что *не-я (так ли вообще стоит его писать?)* из вашего примера. Только оно не переосмысляется... Да, вопрос спорный

Comment: Aer, да я ж и не говорю, что это одно и то же. Я говорю, что и в том случае и в другом случае нет просто другого, кроме дефисного, варианта решить дело в рамках орфографии. Можно кавычки поставить, но это уже слишком книжно получится, методами пунктуации.  Так что пол сомнением именно тезис о ***заимствовании*** дефиса. Ни больше - ни меньше.

Comment: да-да, я согласен с вами.

Answer (score 0):

Понятие *не-я* было введено немецким философом Иога́нном Го́тлибом Фи́хте. Слово *не-я* является словообразовательной калькой немецкого *Nicht-Ich* (ср. англ. *Not-I* или исп. *No-Yo*, также калькированные), с чем связано и дефисное написание.